# Issue with "toUpperCase" which outputs "function toUpperCase() { [native code] }" instead of desired output. Make loop stop when a value is reached

Tags: javascript, loops, case-sensitive

So basically I have to following snippet of script :

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            result = window.prompt('Rock, Paper or Scissor?', 'What do you choose?') //prompt user to input choice
            let playerSelection = result.toUpperCase
            console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay())) // to see that loop for "playRound works"
        }
```

It works fine before I add "toUpperCase" after "let playerSelection = result.toUpperCase" (which I do in order to make user able to input any variant of e.g "RoCK", "ROCK", "rock" and "RocK"). After I've added the "toUpperCase" I get the wrong output in the console. Instead of desired output I get: "function toUpperCase() { [native code] }" which I'm looking to fix.

Here is my full script:

```
    let computerScore = 0
let playerScore = 0


function computerPlay (){
    const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"];
    const randomChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

    return(randomChoice);
    }

function playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay) { //This is the actual round, increments "playerScore" and "computerScore" based on who wins round
if (playerSelection == computerPlay) {
        result = `Computer also choose ${computerPlay}! It's a Draw!`;
    } else if ((playerSelection == "Paper" && computerPlay == "Rock") ||
               (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerPlay == "Scissor") ||
               (playerSelection == "Scissor" && computerPlay == "Paper")) {
                   playerScore = playerScore + 1;
                   result = `Computer choose: ${computerPlay}! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerPlay}. You get one point! Your score is: ${playerScore} Computer score is: ${computerScore}`;
               } else {
                computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                   result = `Computer choose: ${computerPlay}! ${computerPlay} beats ${playerSelection}. Computer gets one point! Your score is: ${playerScore} Computer score is: ${computerScore}`;
               } 

            return (result);
        }    

       // console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay())) // to test if function "playRound works"

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            result = window.prompt('Rock, Paper or Scissor?', 'What do you choose?') //prompt user to input choice
            let playerSelection = result.toUpperCase
            console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay())) // to see that loop for "playRound works"
        }

        function winLose () { //to give output based on who wins or loses (or if draw)
            if (playerScore > computerScore){
                console.log(`You won over the computer with ${playerScore} points. Yay! You sure showed that computer who's boss!`) 
            } else if (computerScore > playerScore) {
                console.log(`The computer won over you with ${computerScore} points. Oh no! You are inferior to the computer!`)
            } else if (playerScore == computerScore){
                console.log(`You had ${playerScore} points and the computer had ${computerScore} points. No one wins! Boring...`)
            } else {
                console.log("You and the computer where both unlucky and had too many draws to decide who's the superior life form")
            }
        }
        winLose()
```

I'm also wondering how to make the "loop" I have stop, once either the "computerScore" or "playerScore" reaches 3. Since it doesn't make sense to get prompted to keep playing once you've lost or won 3 times.

Thanks for any pointers and help!

Comment: The error is clear. You reference the function object, instead of *calling* the function. Add parentheses to make the call.

Comment: toUpperCase is a string method, so it would be result.toUpperCase()

Answer (score 1):

The Error is basically that you are using `toUpperCase` like a property instead of a function call. To call the function on the string, you need to add parentheses:

```
let playerSelection = result.toUpperCase()
```

But judging your code, I don't think that you want this function. What it does is turning every character into it's uppercase version, so paper will become PAPER. I think you had more something like a capitalize function in mind, like this paper --> Paper. In order for your code to work, you will also have to change your playround function to this:

```
 else if ((playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerPlay == "Rock") ||
           (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerPlay == "Scissor") ||
           (playerSelection == "SCISSOR" && computerPlay == "Paper"))
```

Comment: Happy to help :-)